# How to hide a label tag in JavaScript that has a certain value for the “for” attribute?

Tags: javascript

The label's "for" attribute has the ID of a Radio button. I 'm able to hide the radio button but not the label. How can I hide the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery:

```
$('#radio_btn').hide();
$('label[for="radio_btn"]').hide();
```

Or with different markup:

HTML:

```
<label for="radio"><input type="radio" id="radio"> Radio</label>​
```

JS:

```
$('label[for="radio"]').hide();
```